Book recommendation: NURBS curve and surfaces.
I want to learn NURBS curves and surfaces (related to CAD) by myself, in order to construct some 'irregular' examples. I have studied differential geometry, differential manifold. But until now I know little about the related stuff, such as $B$-spline curve/ surface, Briezer curve/surface, etc.
Any books/ thesis recommended in this field? Thanks in advance.

Here are a few that I have found useful over the years:
The NURBS book by Piegl is a good starting point: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-59223-2
Another one is Nurbs: From Projective Geometry to Practical Use by Farin:
https://www.amazon.com/Nurbs-Projective-Geometry-Practical-Use/dp/1568810849
A free resource is this one A Primer on Bézier Curves:
https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/
Finally, Sederberg's book Computer Aided Geometric Design:
https://www.scribd.com/document/217489808/CAGD-Notes-Sederberg

Many thanks to your recommendation! :)
